# Excel : get_Range(cellName).Text gives only 8000 characters from cell. Here Cell has total 20000 characters

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

```
Range rng = this.workSheet.get_Range(cellName);
rng.Select();

return Convert.ToString(rng.Text);
```

It gives only 8221 characters of specific cell. Actually that cell has near to 20000 characters.

Comment: Did you try
return this.workSheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString();

Comment: yes, it gives me all the characters. But let say, Date is set in the cell with custom format. Text property gives me the custom formated date value, but get_value() function gives me date time value. So it causes regression.

Comment: Perhaps you could test for length of the string, and decide whether to use .Value or .Text based on those results.

Comment: I've seen this issue before but do not remember how I solved it.  Make sure you are use the ACE in the connection string which max values are larger than JET.  Also recommend saving the excel as xlsx (not xls) where limits are larger.

Comment: I suspect the .Text property only returns the text Excel displays in the cell, which may be less than the actual cell content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.workSheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString();
```